# CALL-ME with gather/take used in a hyper method chain doesn't work

Tags: raku

Been playing with method chaining and `CALL-ME`

Below is a toy class I'm using to play with. The `CALL-ME` just invokes the `double` method for the Seq of values it gets given.

```
class Math does Callable
{
    method  CALL-ME(Iterable:D $i)
    {
        gather {
            $i.map: -> $v { take self.double($v) } ;
        }
    }

    method double($x) { return $x * 2}
}

my $d = Math.new();
```

First check that it is possible to include the `Math` object, `$d`, in a method chain.

This code

```
(1,2,3).map( * + 1 ).$d.map( * +1).say;
```

outputs the correct result

```
(5 7 9)
```

Now put `hyper` into the method chain

```
(1,2,3).hyper.map( * + 1 ).$d.map( * + 1 ).say;
```

Output this time is

```
A worker in a parallel iteration (hyper or race) initiated here:
  in block <unit> at callme.raku line 6

Died at:
    take without gather
      in block  at callme.raku line 6
```

where line 6 is the `take` line.

I can work around the issue by replacing the `CALL-ME` with another call to `map` (as below), but that leaves the question as to why `map` can do-the-right-thing, but `CALL-ME` cannot?

```
(1,2,3).hyper.map( * + 1 ).map( -> $v { $d.double($v) } ).map( * +1).say;
```

Have I missed something?

**[EDIT]** Update following reply from Rawley.

Say I create a larger class that also includes a `CALL-ME`. Ideally I'd like the method chaining to run optimally in both a serial and concurrent workflow without the user having to jump through too many hoops.

If I leave the `gather`/`take` in the `CALL-ME` I get lazy execution when used in a serial context, but it breaks completely when `hyper` is used.

Alternatively, removing the `gather`/`take` means I have a `CALL-ME` that works in both a serial & hyper context. The downside is the serial use-case ends up running in eager mode.

Is there a way for `CALL-ME` to have it both ways by testing the context it is running in?

Something like the hypothetical `is-hyper-active` below

```
    method  CALL-ME(Iterable:D $i)
    {
        if is-hyper-active {
            $i.map: -> $v { take self.double($v)
        } else {
            gather {
                $i.map: -> $v { take self.double($v) } ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

`Hyper` is a lot different from traditional `Seq`, using `gather` and `take` most likely won't work because of the asynchronicity of `Hyper`. Instead you can drop the `gather` and `take` from your `CALL-ME` and simply return the result of the map to make this work:

```
class Math does Callable {
    method CALL-ME(Iterable:D $i) {
        $i.map: -> $t { self.double($t) };
    }

    method double($x) { return $x * 2}
}
```

Now you should see that:

```
(1,2,3).hyper.map( * + 1 ).$d.map( * + 1 ).say;
```

works.

Personally, I avoid `gather` and `take` and prefer to just use methods and functions to construct my `Seq`'s. Also it's a little more idiomatic to omit the `return` on functions that don't return in multiple places.

Comment: Thanks, but does that not now break the laziness of the method chain?  The knock-on is if I want a CALL-ME to work with or without hyper, I'm have to sacrifice laziness?

Comment: @pmqs The main selling point of Hyper is concurrent operations, think of it like SIMD for seq elements. Not sure where you're getting lazyness from, HyperSeq's are [not lazy](https://docs.raku.org/type/HyperSeq.html#method_is-lazy).

Comment: Sorry @Rawley, that wasn't my point. All I'm saying is that if I create a utility `CALL-ME` for a library, I will have no control over how it will be used. If I want it to work in both a serial & concurrent (with hyper) setup, it sound like I need to sacrifice the lazy execution of the serial version. Unless, that is,  there is a way in the `CALL-ME` to tell when it is being executed in a serial or concurrent context?

Comment: @pmqs Ah I see. From what I can tell, yes you will have to. Personally I think this makes sense to have 2 functions rather than an object and two classes, say `math-lazy` and `math`, then swap them accordingly `(1,2,3).hyper.map( * + 1 ).&math.map( * + 1 ).say;`